# My map won't move with openlayers 6.2 and angular 9, even with DragRotateAndZoom interaction

Tags: angular9, openlayers-6

I'm trying to create a map, and as I can see on other sites and examples, everyone can move their map with mouseclick and drag. But my map wont move at all, anyone have idea what I did wrong?

These are the components.ts and the component.html files that I am using. I followed instructions on https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html, without installing parcel because I'm using angular.

map.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.mapInit();
  }

   mapInit() {
   var mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
         coordinateFormat: createStringXY(4),
         projection: 'EPSG:4326',
         // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
         // be placed within the map.
         className: 'custom-mouse-position',
         target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
         undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
       });

          var source = new OSM();
          var overviewMapControl = new OverviewMap({
            layers: [
              new TileLayer({
                source: source
              })
            ]
          });

          this.map = new Map({
          target: 'map',
          interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([
              new DragRotateAndZoom
            ]),
            layers: [
              new TileLayer({
                source: source
              }),
            ],
            view: new View({
              center: fromLonLat([19.833549, 45.267136]),
              zoom: 7
            }),
            controls: defaultControls().extend([
            overviewMapControl,
            new FullScreen(),
            mousePositionControl,
            new ZoomToExtent({
            extent: [
               813079.7791264898, 5929220.284081122,
               848966.9639063801, 5936863.986909639,
             ]
             })
            ])
          });
```

map.component.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Drag, Rotate, and Zoom</title>
  <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch,requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="mouse-position"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the same as this issue: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10663

The latest version of ol.css isn't included in the HTML.

Add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's work for version 6.2.* and 6.3.*, but for me it does not work since version 6.4.0. Since this commit : https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/commit/7f6258dd0d96cbfb16764f7b2af1ad0af2735cc3

Comment: That is probably a different issue, hard to tell without a [mcve] (and that would be another question)